# Naming Plural with two items

Tags: ios, controller, naming-conventions, naming

I'm making a controller shows list of cells(UITableViewController in iOS).
Let's say each cells contain a book and a pen(just for ex.).

How can I name the controller?

The name I came up with was "BooksPensController" and I wonder this is a
proper way of naming it.

Is the naming above relevant? and if not what should the name be?

Answer (score 0):

I think its better approach to name a controller generic  rather than specifically naming the individual items shown on the screen
Specifically in this case, I think you can name it as StationaryListViewController or StationaryTableViewController, so if after sometime you want to add pencils or notebooks , it wont be needed to change

Comment: Sorry to mention that I wasn't actually listing books and pens.  I was just for an example.  I tried to generalize what are shown in the cell but there wasn't any reasonable word for my case...

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to ViewController type as suffix to name. If its UIViewController I will prefer BooksViewcontroller if its UITableViewController  i will prefer BooksTableViewController. You should choose name keeping in my mind, that you can get its context by its name 
in future.